# Link to open directory in Windows Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible in VSC to add a URL that opens a directory in Windows Exporer?

For example: "file:///C:/"

This should open Windows Explorer in the C directory.

[image]

It doens't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to add this link? In a webpage? Not that's not possible for security reasons. Furthermore what would happen on a Linux based system?

Comment: In the editor. I added a screenshot so you know what I mean.